# photos randomly disappearing from iphone

Tags: iphone, icloud, photos, data-synchronization

My father has iPhone 8 same as me. He has been suffering from a strange issue when photos suddenly disappear. But not all. He takes a picture and when he wants to check it later, it is not in the photos. But it is not happening for all photos. Just some. It seems very random. I personally have never encountered that.
He has his phone connected to iCloud and his mac is connected to the same icloud account as well. The photos are not on the mac either.

- Has anyone experienced something like this (i am talking about random picture loss not all at once due to icloud logout)
- How would photos behave if one has icloud sync enabled but is out of space because one stopped paying for additional storage? Could this happen that iphone would delete some photos to be able to upload others?

Comment: Clarifications please: Pop uses auto-upload to iCloud Photos exclusively? iCloud storage full or not?

Comment: @IconDaemon For the times when he has a physical proof of the existence of the photo (printed version), the iCloud sync of photos was enabled. However, at that time, he was not paying for the storage and was downgraded from 50GB to 5GB and iCloud was full. The problem for me is that it is very difficult to replicate the problem. Also, this tends to happen for older photos. Say, he takes some important pictures for work and needs to check them 3 months later and they are gone. That is a big issue. (Also he currently has almost 5000 pictures in the iPhone)

Comment: I have never used iCloud Photos as I lost a bunch of photos when I tried it the first (and last) time. I have never lost a photo since and have used AirDrop and Image Capture to move photos from my phone to various Macs ever since.